# Android connecting server, how do I stop the socket after a certain amount of time?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm developing a personal android application used at home for my own functionality.

I am trying to make it so that if the Server at home is either down or non-functional, it will disconnect after 3 seconds.

Here's my code:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 26753);
socket.setSoTimeout(3000);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
out.println("y" + e.getText().toString());
out.println("u" + a.getText().toString());
out.println("EOF");
socket.close();
```

**Ignore the EOF at the end. That is there so that my server knows when to close the socket**

So I've put setSoTimeout to 3000 (3 seconds), but android application doesn't respond. Can I put it in a thread, how would I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try using a connect timeout:

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.setSoTimeout(3000);
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("10.0.2.2", 26753), 3000);
```